# Using VAR model in statsmodel returning errors

Tags: python, linear-algebra, statsmodels

I am trying to use Vector Autoregression(VAR) model in statsmodel for my research. The input data is a matrix with high dimensional vector. The code is as follows:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model import VAR
model = VAR(data)
fit = model.fit(maxlags=3,ic='aic')
test = fit.forecast(1)
```

However when I executed it I got an error like:

```
File "/Users/Documents/code/VAR.py", line 39, in test_var
fit = model.fit(maxlags=3,ic='aic')
File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/vector_ar/var_model.py", line 423, in fit
selections = self.select_order(maxlags=maxlags, verbose=verbose)
File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/vector_ar/var_model.py", line 508, in select_order
for k, v in iteritems(result.info_criteria):
File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/base/wrapper.py", line 35, in __getattribute__
obj = getattr(results, attr)
File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/decorators.py", line 97, in __get__
_cachedval = self.fget(obj)
File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/vector_ar/var_model.py", line 1471, in info_criteria
ld = logdet_symm(self.sigma_u_mle)
File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/linalg.py", line 219, in logdet_symm
c, _ = linalg.cho_factor(m, lower=True)
File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_cholesky.py", line 132, in cho_factor
check_finite=check_finite)
raise LinAlgError("%d-th leading minor not positive definite" % info)
```

numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 98-th leading minor not positive definite

I am not so familiar with the mathematical theories here and I am wondering how to fix this problem.(e.g. Are there any data preprocessing methods should I conduct first.)

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? So we can see who is responsible for throwing that error and what the call chain looked like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added the error information.

Comment: Relevant? https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2342

Comment: I tried PCA but still got this error.

Comment: Even with PCA you can have too many components and parameters. It looks like `sigma_u_mle` is singular and you might still have more parameters than observations. A full VAR is very limited in the number of variables because the number of parameters increases very fast.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I added more samples to solve this problem.